# Окантовка вокруг букв

Tags: css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать окантовку вокруг быкв, не тень, а чёрную окантовку. Не знаю, как и поступить.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать как раз-таки тенью:

```
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Всё ясно!

Answer (score -1):

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
```